# Remove trailing slash from $uri in nginx?

Tags: nginx

I am caching my websites pages into a static flat file cache and am trying to use a try_files directive to load the file first from cache if it exists and then go to web application.

I'm basically trying to do something like this:

```
 try_files $uri $uri/ /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/staticfilecache/$uri/index.html
```

In this example if the user requested example.com/products/ it would try staticfilecache/products/index.html The problem I have is that $uri already contains a trailing slash. Trying to use this with $uriindex.html creates an error.

Is there any performant/easy way to always strip the / but not rewrite the address in the browser?

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do has many problems on many levels.

1. "/var/www/vhosts/$uri" is invalid. Except if you have duplicated
   your whole document root under the staticfilecache folder.
2. Nginx has it's own caching system and will check it first by itself
   without any intervention from you as long as it has been setup.
3. Nginx will check for index files by itself as long as the index directive has been set.
4. Your code is actually attempting to check the staticcache last and
   not first as you said you wanted.
5. There is no point in creating a static file cache on disk. Nginx can
   just as well read the static files from their original locations.
6. In any case, Nginx will create the cache for items that need cache,
   usually dynamic files, by itself. It is not a manual job.

Basically, it looks like you are a bit on the wrong track on some webserver fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

The answer(strictly) to your question is,

```
rewrite ^(.*)/$ $1 break;
```

But I would recommend you don't do this and go through @Dayo's answer.

For some interesting stuff for caching guidance, you can check [this out](http://www.techromance.com/2015/11/11/microcaching-in-nginx-web-server/).